# I can't find the equation of a line with the slope of -8 that has one point of intersection with the parabola y=x^2-4x+5

Tags: functions, quadratics, problem-solving

Im having a lot of trouble figuring out the equation of a line (that has the slope of -8) and has only one point intersecting with a parabola y=x^2-4x +5. Im not sure how to isolate b once I combine the 2 equations

Comment: Hint1 : Such a line must be a tangent on the parabola

Comment: Hint2 : Solve the eqaution $2x-4=-8$

Comment: You mention that you do not know how to isolate $b$, but you do not mention $b$ at any other time...  Could you show your work so that others can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Since the slope is $-8$ you know that the equation of the line has the form $y=-8x+b$

It intersects with the parabola $y=x^2-4x+5$

At the intersection point(s) we know that the $y$ value of the line and the parabola are equal so let's put the two equations equal to each other

$-8x+b=x^2-4x+5$

Now solving for $x$ will tell us the $x$ point(s) of the intersection

$0=x^2+4x+(5-b)$

There is only one intersection point so this quadratic equation has only one real root, can you find out what value of $b$ gives only one real root?

Answer (score 1):

Hugh's answer is good. To use Peter's hint:

In order to touch the parabola only once, the line must be a tangent. So when does the parabola have gradient $-8$?

$$
y = x^2 - 4x -5
$$
$$
{dy\over dx} = 2x - 4
$$
So we require 
$$
-8 = 2x - 4
$$
i.e
$$
x = -2
$$
To complete, calculate $y$ when $x=-2$ and then fit it to the line, i.e. solve
$$
y = -8x + b
$$
to calculate the $y$-intercept $b$.

Comment: @LaehC Note this answer uses calculus which you may or may not have learnt yet. If you haven't learnt calculus then look at Hugh's answer.